# Interbase Event support in c#

Tags: c#, interbase

Well, actually my question is fairly simple: Is there support for Interbase events in C#? In Delphi there is the TIBEvent class, but I cannot find such a thing for C#.

The only thing I can think of is using the GDS32 dll directly or creating a Delphi dll myself that is using the TIBEvent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer is pretty straightforward too... You actually provided it yourself already!

Currently Interbase ADO 2.0 .NET driver does not support IBX (Interbase Express) components. Unfortunately, the TIBEvent class supported with RAD Studio is just one of these IBX components. See [the devguide for Interbase (XE7) for more information](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IBXE7/DevGuide.pdf).

Therefore the answer would be lying in your last thought. Use the GDS32.dll directly by calling it from your C# application or (as just another example) by creating a DLL with Delphi (also from Embarcadero) wrapping and utilizing the TIBEvent class. Then you could also use that DLL from your C# application.

I know that this is probably not the answer you would hope to receive, but at least it is one that points towards your own solution.